# Call to AmazonAPI keeps returning http 403 error

Tags: python, amazon-product-api

I am new to Python and am trying to make a call to the Amazon API:

```
from amazon.api import AmazonAPI

amazon = AmazonAPI(ac_key, sc_key, as_tag)

products = amazon.search(Keywords='kindle', SearchIndex='All')
for i, product in enumerate(products):
print "{0}. '{1}'".format(i, product.title)
```

However, I keep getting this error. Can anyone help me understand why?

```
    File
 "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
 line 558, in http_error_default
     raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
     urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: Have you checked your access and secret keys? Error 403 means that you do not have access to the specific resource which generally happens when your "login" info is incorrect.

Comment: Probably you don't have access to that page, maybe it demands login.